# Change div css after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change some valeues after clicking on this div (I use it like a button). I want to change for example width and height to 200.

html:

```
<div class = "sq" onclick="main.function();">
...
</div>
```

css:

```
.sq {
    width: 102.5px;
    height: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I edited post. I want to change for example width and height to 200 after clicking it. I have many buttons and I want only active (clicked) to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using css only.

```
button:focus {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Here is a pen as example. http://codepen.io/doggard/pen/PzERxg

edit: you can use the same approach on a div by adding a tabindex attribute to the div.

```
<div tabindex="1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want .sq div to change width and height when it's clicked?

If so, if you don't mind using Jquery, you could do something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.sq').click(function() {
            $(this).css('height','200px');
            $(this).css('width','200px');       
        })      
    })
</script>
<div class="sq">

</div>
```

Comment: Yes. I have a few buttons and i want to change only one of them at the time and the rest should be the same as original css. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: The above should do this - if they all have the class .sq then it will change the height and width only on the object you clicked, and not affecting the other ones. If you want to toggle between different widths and heights, there are better solutions below than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.sq-unique').click(function(){
    $('.sq-unique').toggleClass('sqClick');
  });
});
```

```css
.sq {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 102.5px;
    height: 2px;
    float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}    

.sq-unique {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 102.5px;
    height: 2px;
    float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sq-unique.sqClick {
   height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sq-unique">
&nbsp;
</div>

<div class="sq">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: I have a few buttons and i want to change only one of them at the time and the rest should be the same as original css. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the .sq class to be a unique .sq-unique class (rename it as you see fit). Then you can use it on just one element, or multiple.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sq-click').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.sq {
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  width: 80px;
}

.sq-click.active {
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sq sq-click">Button 1</div>
<div class="sq">Button 2</div>
<div class="sq">Button 3</div>
<div class="sq">Button 4</div>
```

Comment: I have a few buttons and i want to change only one of them at the time and the rest should be the same as original css. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class = "sq" onclick="changeDimensions();">
```

Pure javascript:

```
function changeDimensions(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("sq").style.width = "200px";
  document.getElementsByClassName("sq").style.height = "200px";
}
```